# Doubly Linked List using Stack in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel, stack

Just started learning/relearning data structures for the semester exams. Most of the examples found online are too cluttered or bloated.

For myself, I implemented it from theory I learned.

It works.

I want to know if there are any mistake that I have done, anything that can be improved .. .

Thanks for your time :)

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

struct Node{

    struct Node* prev;
    int data;
    struct Node* next;

};

Node* top = NULL;

bool isempty(){
    return  top->prev == NULL;
}

void push(int data){

    struct Node* newnode;
    newnode = new Node();

    if(!newnode){
        cout << "Heap Overflow" << endl;
    }

    newnode->prev = top;
    newnode->data = data;  
    newnode->next = NULL;

    top = newnode;
}

void pop(){

    if(isempty()){
        cout << "Stack Underflow";
        exit(1);
    }

    struct Node* tmp;
    tmp = new Node();

    tmp->next = NULL;
    tmp->data = top->prev->data;
    tmp->prev = top->prev->prev;

    free(top);
    top = tmp;

}

void display(){

    struct Node* itr;
    itr = top;

    cout << itr->data << " ";
    while(itr->prev != NULL){
        cout << itr->prev->data << " ";
        itr = itr->prev;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){

    push(10);
    push(20);
    push(30);
    push(40);
    push(50);

    pop();
    display();
    pop();
    display();
    pop();
    display();
    pop();
    display();
    pop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You can take the [tour] for an overview of our site. I have added the [reinventing-the-wheel]  tag for you.  This tag is appropriate for questions that re-implement existing functionalities for whatever reason (e.g., learning or fun).

Comment: Isn't this actualy a stack implemented as doubly linked list, instead of the other way around? And if so, why doubly linked list? You only need one way linked list to implement stack.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Code Review!

## Bugs

For every node you insert, `next` is null.

## Encapsulation

Your code is written almost exclusively using C features.  First things first, instead of using a single global variable, use a class to encapsulate the data structure.

```
class Stack {
public:
    Stack() = default;
    Stack(const Stack&) = delete;
    Stack& operator=(const Stack&) = delete;
    ~Stack();

    void push(int data);
    void pop();
    void display() const;
    bool empty() const { return top == nullptr; }
private:
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* top = nullptr;
};
```

The way the function works is exactly the same.  A destructor should be provided to systematically handle memory deallocation:

```
Stack::~Stack()
{
    while (!empty()) {
        pop();
    }
}
```

Now `Stack` can be used like a normal C++ container:

```
int main()
{
    Stack stack1;
    stack1.push(3);
    stack1.push(1);
    stack1.push(4);
    stack1.display();
    stack1.pop();
    stack1.display();

    Stack stack2;
    // stack2 is a stack independent from stack1
} // the existing nodes are automatically freed when the main function returns
```

## Miscellaneous

`#include "..."` is for your own headers.  For standard headers, use `#include <iostream>`.

`using namespace std;` at global level is considered bad practice and should be avoided because it defeats the purpose of namespaces and introduce name clashes.  You will have trouble using identifiers as common as `size` or `count`.  See [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

A class can be referred to directly with its name.  You don't need to add `struct`.  So instead of `struct Node*`, just say `Node*`.

Instead of `NULL`, use `nullptr` for null pointer constants.

It's more common to write functions in this way:

```
bool isempty()
{
    // ...
}
```

Instead of declaring a variable uninitialized and then assigning to it immediately, use initialization.

The `push` and `pop` functions are way too convoluted.  Remember you are implementing a stack, not a complete doubly linked list.  Aggregate initialization with `new` can be used to simplify the code:

```
void Stack::push(int value)
{
    top = new Node{value, top, nullptr};
    if (auto old = top->prev) {
        old->next = top;
    }
}

void Stack::pop()
{
    if (empty()) {
        throw Stack_underflow{};
    }
    delete std::exchange(top, top->prev);
}
```

Note that heap overflow is not something you need to worry about because `new` already throws an appropriate exception on allocation failure.  Also, do not free memory allocated by `new` with `free`.  This is undefined behavior.  Use `new` with `delete` instead.

When an error happens, throw an exception instead of printing a message and then exiting or even continuing execution.  There is not always an open `stdout` file, and if it exists, that's now how everyone wants error to be handled.  Throwing an exception allows the user to handle it in the convenient way.

The `while` loop in the display function should have been simplified with a `for` loop:

```
for (Node* itr = top; itr; itr = itr->prev) {
    std::cout << itr->data << '\n';
}
```

Note that `std::endl` should be avoided when you don't need the flushing semantics.  Unnecessary flushing can cause performance degradation.  See [`std::endl` vs `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907).

`return 0;` can be omitted in a `main` function.

## Refined version

Putting everything together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

struct Stack_underflow :std::exception {};

class Stack {
public:
    Stack() = default;
    Stack(const Stack&) = delete;
    Stack& operator=(const Stack&) = delete;
    ~Stack();

    void push(int value);
    void pop();
    void display() const;
    bool empty() const { return top == nullptr; }
private:
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* top = nullptr;
};

Stack::~Stack()
{
    while (!empty()) {
        pop();
    }
}

void Stack::push(int value)
{
    top = new Node{value, top, nullptr};
    if (auto old = top->prev) {
        old->next = top;
    }
}

void Stack::pop()
{
    if (empty()) {
        throw Stack_underflow{};
    }
    delete std::exchange(top, top->prev);
}

void Stack::display() const
{
    for (auto it = top; it; it = it->prev) {
        std::cout << it->data << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Stack stack;
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(3);
    stack.push(4);
    stack.push(5);

    stack.pop();
    stack.display();
    stack.pop();
    stack.display();
}
```

Output:

```
4 3 2 1 
3 2 1
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5xgI53mz5YziXoCK))

Comment: Let me just note that the `display()` method should not be a member. It can be `std::basic_ostream & operator<<(std::basic_ostream &, const Stack &);` instead (but it would have to be made friend of the `Stack` and let `Node *top` be protected, or otherwise accessible by the operator overload).

Comment: @slepic That’s right.  I guess that’s a bit too much for the “semester exams” though.